# Getting Enumerate to work as ExactSizeIterator in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to use Rust's [`Enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Enumerate.html) to get both a character and its index in the slice from each iteration:

```
fn main() {
    for (j, val) in "dummy string".chars().enumerate().rev() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I compile with `cargo run` I get:

```
error: the trait `core::iter::ExactSizeIterator` is not implemented for the type `core::str::Chars<'_>` [E0277]
    for (j, val) in "dummy string".chars().enumerate().rev() {
                                                       ^~~
help: see the detailed explanation for E0277

error: the trait `core::iter::ExactSizeIterator` is not implemented for the type `core::str::Chars<'_>` [E0277]
    for (j, val) in "dummy string".chars().enumerate().rev() {
        // ...
    }
```

I can understand why this would fail: the `rev` method needs an `ExactSizeIterator` since it needs to know the last element in the slice and its index from the beginning. Is it possible to get an `ExactSizeIterator` in this case, or does the length of the iterator need to be baked in at compile time? If it is possible, is it just a matter of specifying the iterator with something like `as ExactSizeIterator` or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [docs for `ExactSizeIterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html) state:

> An iterator that knows its exact length.
>
> Many `Iterator`s don't know how many times they will iterate, but some do. If an iterator knows how many times it can iterate, providing access to that information can be useful. For example, if you want to iterate backwards, a good start is to know where the end is.

But that's not the actual trait required by `rev`!

```
fn rev(self) -> Rev<Self> 
    where Self: DoubleEndedIterator
```

The `ExactSizeIterator` requirement comes from `Enumerate`'s implementation of `DoubleEndedIterator`:

```
impl<I> DoubleEndedIterator for Enumerate<I>
    where I: ExactSizeIterator + DoubleEndedIterator
```

> Is it possible to get an `ExactSizeIterator` in this case, or does the length of the iterator need to be baked in at compile time?

The `Chars` iterator needs to support *both* `ExactSizeIterator` and `DoubleEndedIterator`, but it only natively supports `DoubleEndedIterator`.

In order to implement `ExactSizeIterator` for `Chars`, you'd need to be able to look at an arbitrary string and know (in a small enough time) how many characters it is made of. This is not generally possible with the UTF-8 encoding, the only encoding of Rust strings.

The length of the iterator is never a compile-time constant.

> is it just a matter of specifying the iterator with something like `as ExactSizeIterator`

You cannot make a type into something it is not.

If you *really* need this, you could collect it all into a big `Vec`:

```
fn main() {
    let chars: Vec<_> = "dummy string".chars().collect();
    for (j, val) in chars.into_iter().enumerate().rev() {
        println!("{}, {}", j, val)
    }
}
```

It's also possible you actually want the characters in reverse order with the count in increasing direction:

```
fn main() {
    for (j, val) in "dummy string".chars().rev().enumerate() {
        println!("{}, {}", j, val)
    }
}
```

But you said this:

> a character and its index in the slice

Since strings are UTF-8, it's possible you mean you want the number of *bytes* into the slice. That can be found with the [`char_indices`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) iterator:

```
fn main() {
    for (j, val) in "dummy string".char_indices().rev() {
        println!("{}, {}", j, val)
    }
}
```